# Can't add css in Magento

Tags: php, html, css, magento, xhtml

Have a custom template for my home page placed in mytheme/layout/page/customhome.phtml

To apply it to the home page i had to use the admin CMS as local.xml can't change the template for the home page. I used this code to do that in the custom layout update xml box:

```
 <reference name="root">
     <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/homes.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

That worked, and the home page is using my template, but Magento isn't importing ANY css files into the head section of the page. Not even default ones like styles.css. I've tried to add my own with xml update like above and by using local.xml and referencing head but just nothing works.

Any ideas? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the change of the template. From the phtml file you need made the $this->getChildHtml() corresponding. If you go to your old template in app/design/frontend/base/page/3colums.phtml for example you can see the next command lines:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col3-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-wrapper">
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok, then you be careful with this, all block in yout template need a getChildHtml() from the corespondig phtml. In your case is probably that you don´t add this call from the template. 
Then don´t work head, content, footer, etc.
I think this is your ploblem, nonetheless you can write the content of your custom template to help you with the solution.
Hope help you

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. Can you see any problem in my template? Here it is: http://pastebin.com/jVGvKzL3

Comment: Ah i missed the head part. I'd rather make all changes in a local.xml than page.xmp though. Btw, is '<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?> necessary?

Comment: In page.xml you defin your Global structure of your page, for example, if you want made 5columns, ok. Then after_body_start is very useful because is block to add contend just before tag <body> in your HTML. You migth pay attention the type of block after_body_start, this is core/text_list. This implies that all you add to this block is automatically print in your html. To understand this you should go to method _toHtml of Mage_Core_Block_text_List.

Answer (score 0):

To get Magento CSS and js you need to have

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
```

inside you `<head>` tags so that it would go and fetch them from page.xml

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

                <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            </block>
```

Once you have this, you should get the CSS and js that Magento needs.  should add your CSS in this as well, under your package/theme's page.xml via

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/customs.css</stylesheet></action>
```

and make sure that you have the file in your theme's css folder